get error when run flutter doctor command
enter image description here
[!] Network resources
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://cocoapods.org/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware
installed on your computer.

Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please update your question with the error code you posted as an image in text form so people can assist you.
